# How to get device ID

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, input-devices, synaptics, devices

I am using ubuntu 11.04 on my system. I want to disable the touchpad of the laptop, and for that I need the device id. Can anybody explain how to find the device ID of my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of devices with the `xinput list` command.  This should give output something like this (note the device IDs):

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. ThinkPad USB Keyboard with TrackPoint    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logitech USB Headset             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. ThinkPad USB Keyboard with TrackPoint    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

You can disable a device by *floating* it.  For example, I can disable the TrackPoint on my system with:

```
xinput float 12
```

You can re-enable a device by attaching it to the corresponding master device:

```
xinput reattach 12 2
```

It is also possible to use the device names instead of numeric IDs (e.g. `"Virtual core pointer"` instead of `2`) with both of these commands if you want to write a script that is independent of the numeric IDs.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean from device id is serial number then you find this way

```
sudo dmidecode -t system | grep Serial
```

Output:
Serial Number: PC0JDKDKF