# Device id in ubuntu

Tags: 11.04, xorg, touchpad, input-devices

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop.I want to make the the touchpad disable.For that I need the device id.So can any one tell me how to get the device id using ubuntu?

Comment: lspci should give you what you need.

Comment: I can disable my touchpad using Fn + F1, perhaps you've a similar feature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get synaptics id](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45321/how-to-get-synaptics-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should show the ID

```
xinput --list
```